# Cant get security to work on my web application

Tags: php, security

ok, i need a little help. im attempting to implement a security class and refer in my code as:

```
Security::module('testmodule','view')
```

the class is as follows:

```
class Security extends Model {    
 function module($module,$action) {    
  if(Session::get($module[$action])==1)    
   return true;    
  else    
    return false;
   }
 }
```

the Session has been loaded with:

```
[testmodule] => Array ( [add] => 0 [edit] => 0 [view] => 0 [update] => 0 [activation] => 0 [delete] => 0 [print] => 0 )
```

the problem, i am still being able to view the data that should be restricted. how can i correct this issue. i have more information if needed

Comment: I don't understand code like `if(x) return true; else return false;` why not `return x;` ? Anyway: `$module == 'testmodul'` so `$module['view']` will return `'t'` in php versions < 5.4 and `null` in versions >= 5.4. So you test `if(Session::get('t') == 1)` or `if(Session::get(null) == 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you do with the Result of
`Security::module('testmodule','view')`
?

Do you simply check against true or false?

Also your function definition is dynamic but your Method call to the "module" function is static.